# Gas Regulator Replacement

Tags: natural-gas

We had our gas company come and  or utility room for gas leaks and recommended that I have the gas regulator replaced. I matched up the numbers and ordered it and would like to replace it. Is there anything I should consider before doing it? The unit is a Maxitrol 325-3 and the replacement is a [Maxitrol 325-3L](http://www.maxitrol.com/regulators/leveracting.asp)

Comment: Working with gas piping is not typical a DIY task, if you don't know what you're doing it can end very badly.  With that said... If you have the tools and knowledge necessary for working on gas piping, carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use usual common sense, you know the properties of natural gas.
Always use 2 tools when loosening or tightening fittings or connections.
Do not re-use any lines that have a flare type end.
Try to keep adapters like reducers or gender-changers to a minimum.